# I am having trouble with the DSolve function

Tags: differential-equations

```
DSolve[{x''[t] + 0.01 x'[t] + x[t] == E^(It), x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, x[t], t]
```

This give the following error

> :"Equation or list of equations expected instead of `1` in the first
>   argument.

What would a revised version of this code that solves this differential equation with the two boundary conditions look like? I should note that DSolve finds the solution just fine if omit the boundary condition, why does the inclusion break it?
Edit-- I'm using Mathematica 10, not sure if that matters.

Comment: You used `E^(It)` instead of `E^(I t)`. Note that there should be a space between `I` and `t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
sol = 
  DSolve[{x''[t] + x'[t]/100 + x[t] == Exp[I*t], x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, x[t], t]

(* 
  {{x[t] -> 
    (1/39999) E^(-t/200) 
      ((39999 + 3999900 I) Cos[(Sqrt[39999] t)/200] - 
      3999900 I E^((1/200 + I) t) Cos[(Sqrt[39999] t)/200]^2 - 
      (19799 - 100 I) Sqrt[39999] Sin[(Sqrt[39999] t)/200] - 
      3999900 I E^((1/200 + I) t) Sin[(Sqrt[39999] t)/200]^2)}} 
*)

Plot[Evaluate @ ReIm[x[t] /. sol], {t, -10, 10}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Re[x[t]]", "Im[x[t]]"}]
```

[image]

Comment: So I copied your code and pasted it into a new notebook and it still gives me an error, albeit different: DSolve::deqn: "Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument..." And the error also  shows a little thing in Curly braces {x[t]+x'[t]/100+x''[t]==e^(it), True, x'[0]==1}. Note that I did in fact change to using the Exp[] function instead of E^, and I used "I*t", and changed the decimal 0.01 to a fraction. I am baffled. Oh I have mathematica 10 btw not sure if that helps

Comment: What if you restart Mathematica and then copy, paste, run?

Comment: Weird that it works to just restart it and open another new notebook, now it runs the code with no error. Why is that though?

Comment: Read this: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ClearMyDefinitions.html :)